# Running different js files at sametime in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to NodeJs. Consider I am having three different js files in my folder. When I want to run my node js file, I want to type "node file1.js" in the command prompt. Again when I want to run another js file I have to stop the previously running js file and I must give "node file2.js". Or I have to open new command prompt and run the second js file. Likewise I have to do it for the third file also. This irritated me a lot. Is there any way to run all the js files at sametime without opening new command prompts. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Write a `.sh` or a `.bat`? Do your files communicate with each other?

Comment: some files communicate with each other. I also have files which do not communicate. Also I am not aware of .sh or .bat files. Any tutorials would be helpful.

Comment: `.sh` means a `shell` script run on `*nix`, while `.bat` means a `Batch` run on `windows`. Both of them can loop through a directory and run some command. I will make an answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a bash(one of shell scripts) called `filename.sh` to do these things. If you work on Windows, you can write a `filename.bat` by `Batch`. Here is an example of bash script for you.

```
#!/bin/bash
for d in * ; do
if [[ $d == *\.js ]]
then
    node "$d" &
fi
done
```

If you run command `sh filename.sh` to execute the code above, it will run all the js file in current directory. And you can make some filter rule in `if` block to skip the file you do not want to run. I think you can do it in this way.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid using different command prompts, you may use some "launcher", such as `forever`or `pm2`.

With these, you can run your JS files like this:

```
forever start myJsFile1.js
forever start myJsFile2.js
forever start myJsFile3.js
```

and you can view some stats about your files with `forever list`.

*Documentations:*

- [forever on npm](https://www.npmjs.org/package/forever)
- [pm2 on npm](https://www.npmjs.org/package/pm2)

Another way to get your prompt clean is to put the process in background right after you start it. It will avoid you to start new prompts.

```
node myJsFile1.js &
node myJsFile2.js &
node myJsFile2.js &
```

But, if you really want to launch your files at the **same time** exactly, I don't understand how your program works. Because, you can just start one file and require the others or use them in your main file in some way.